# Search all dates before a specific date in a database (VB.NET|OLE)

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, oledb

I have a database (MDB, Access) and I connect it to my program using an OLE object,
now I have in the db a column filled with dates (ddmmyy),

**I want to search and view (in Data grid view) all the fields that has a date before a Specific Date that I define .**

the code of search that I used is :

```
 SQLstr = "SELECT * FROM tb WHERE anomber = '" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
```

What do I have to do?. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use the parameters to pass the date to the query, it's more saver(no sql injection) and more perfect(it will convert the date format to the correct format)

```
SQLstr = "SELECT * FROM tb WHERE anomber < ?"
Command.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@anomber", TextBox1.Text))
Command.CommandText = SQLstr
```

**Edit:**
if the anomber field is the date field so the user can use < instead of =.

the OP question not clear about what he wants.

Edit2:
after executing the command you should assign the results to the grid that you are using to display the data.

Comment: This won't search the database for records that has a date which is prior to the search date, which the OP wants.

Comment: I mean a have a column with dates , and I have a date in my program (x date) , and want to view all the fields that have any date before this date(x date)

Comment: what I have to add instead of "Command.Parameters" , I don't know , please